# Proactively Determining Bad Plans/Poor Performance at a Query Level

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

tldr; I'm looking for ways to monitor server performance to alert when individual, small, fast queries get a bad plan that will in aggregate hurt the performance of the business.

---

Over the past week we've suddenly had a few stored procedures grab bad query plans, and drag the server to slow downs.  It hasn't been the same query, but it has involved the same tables for one group (which I imagined was a statistics problem), and when we FREEPROCCACHE'd the server another query got a bad plan, and has picked it up at random again.

Being the guy who is held responsible for the server, I'm being asked to do things like ensure no query will ever get a bad plan again, or that I react to it before the users notice the performance degradation.

I have monitoring tools, I'm monitoring long running queries - but this is a case of many queries that run inside 10ms changing to taking 5s, and that's not immediately noticeable, it barely even blips the performance monitoring CPU and memory-wise (apart from more frequent buffer cache dumps perhaps).

For any individual known query I can set up a baseline and an agent job that alerts me, or FREEPROCCACHEs its own plan when it gets a bad plan - but what is my best way to determine this for a busy server?

Should I be baselining run stats for all queries and checking the query stats for all?  Can BlitzCache help me out?  Will this sort of checking be too intrusive on the performance of the server?

Comment: We've got a clustered environment running Enterprise

Comment: We're actually using Spotlight, but it hasn't got great baselining - at least as far as it has been set up. It will let you drill in to view performance of queries that go pass the threshold, but it can't really alert you to any queries going past what they have in the past (that I've found).  I've wanted to evaluate the competitors, but the development team likes what they've always had.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of developing a solution yourself you could consider upgrading to SQL Server 2017 and trying out the [automatic tuning feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/automatic-tuning/automatic-tuning?view=sql-server-2017). Reproducing part of the documentation:

> Database Engine automatically detects any potential plan choice
>   regression including the plan that should be used instead of the wrong
>   plan. When the Database Engine applies the last known good plan, it
>   automatically monitors the performance of the forced plan. If the
>   forced plan is not better than the regressed plan, the new plan will
>   be unforced and the Database Engine will compile a new plan. If
>   Database Engine verifies that the forced plan is better than regressed
>   one, the forced plan will be retained until a recompile (for example,
>   on next statistics or schema change) if it is better than the
>   regressed plan.
>
> Note: Any plans auto forced do not persist on a restart of the SQL
>   Server instance.

This could make it easier to meet the "react to it before the users notice the performance degradation" option.

Comment: Thanks, that's a consideration - but we're starting peak period for our industry until the end of the year and I won't be able to make this upgrade.  When moving to 2014 the team had a lot of trouble with widespread bad plans when the compatibility mode got updated and so we are running on legacy cardinality estimator and an old compatibility mode that would need to be increased in such a shift.  It's too risky a proposition for now, but I agree a good path for future.